# Error attempting to use Subversion after upgrade: Segmentation fault

Tags: debian, gnome3, subversion

I did an apt-get update/upgrade today and my Subversion is giving me grief now.

I am still a new user with Debian so I was not aware that sometimes a reboot is required after one of these updates. I may have messed some things up.

I am running currently:
debian 7, 
gnome 3.4.2,
subversion 1.7.19

Attempting to svn update or svn commit, I get 'segmentation fault' with no other indicator of what is wrong.

The rest of my system seems to work fine so far as I can tell.

What could be causing my issue?

Comment: This may be due to unofficial packages. If you don't have such packages, you can write a bug report. With `gdb`, you can see where the crash occurs. This can give you some idea of the cause of the problem.

Comment: @vinc17 that is a good call.  this subversion was from a 3rd party repo so i could get a newer version to run.  i dont know much about `gdb`  do you have a link where i can read about it?

Comment: `apt-get install gdb`, but anyway, a crash from a Subversion coming from a 3rd-party repo is not surprising, since the ABI's may be different, unless it claims to be Debian-compatible (note: Debian derivatives are not necessarily compatible with Debian). If you want a newer version, use backports if available, or compile it from source.

Comment: the only bug gdb caught was `0x00007ffff642f959 in free () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`

Comment: Assuming you are running the official debian package of subversion, you need to report a bug to debian.  Also, stop using subversion and move to a modern DVCS, like git, bzr, or hg ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting exactly the same issue on Debian Wheezy with svn 1.7.19-1+WANdisco, with the same error reported when running in gdb.

Looking at the stack trace (bt) in gdb showed the problem to be related to Gnome Keyring integration (libsvn_auth_gnome_keyring). I worked around the problem by disabling this in `~/.subversion/config` by disabling external password stores:

`password store =`

FWIW Gnome Keyring integration seemed to work correctly with the SVN 1.8 build from WANdisco (but I had to downgrade to 1.7 for other reasons).